# Is there a way I can force a record to not be destroyed when running a feature test in RSpec? (Rails 6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-6, destroy

For context, I have a controller method called `delete_cars`. Inside of the method, I call `destroy_all` on an `ActiveRecord::Collection` of `Car`s. Below the `destroy_all`, I call another method, `get_car_nums_not_deleted_from_portal`, which looks like the following:

```
def get_car_nums_not_deleted_from_portal(cars_to_be_deleted)
  reloaded_cars = cars_to_be_deleted.reload
  car_nums = reloaded_cars.car_numbers

  if reloaded_cars.any?
    puts "Something went wrong. The following cars were not deleted from the portal: #{car_nums.join(', ')}"
  end

  car_nums
end
```

Here, I check to see if any cars were not deleted during the `destroy_all` transaction. If there are any, I just add a `puts` message. I also return the `ActiveRecord::Collection` whether there are any records or not, so the code to follow can handle it.

The goal with one of my feature tests is to mimic a user trying to delete three selected cars, but one fails to be deleted. When this scenario occurs, I display a specific notice on the page stating:

```
'Some selected cars have been successfully deleted from the portal, however, some have not. The '\
"following cars have not been deleted from the portal:\n\n#{some_car_numbers_go_here}"
```

How can I force just one record to fail when my code executes the `destroy_all`, WITHOUT adding extra code to my `Car` model (in the form of a `before_destroy` or something similar)? I've tried using a spy, but the issue is, when it's created, it's not a real record in the DB, so my query:

```
cars_to_be_deleted = Car.where(id: params[:car_ids].split(',').collect { |id| id.to_i })
```

doesn't include it.

For even more context, here's the test code:

```
context 'when at least one car is not deleted, but the rest are' do
  it "should display a message stating 'Some selected cars have been successfully...' and list out the cars that were not deleted" do
    expect(Car.count).to eq(100)
    visit bulk_edit_cars_path
    select(@location.name.upcase, from: 'Location')
    select(@track.name.upcase, from: 'Track')
    click_button("Search".upcase)

    find_field("cars_to_edit[#{Car.first.id}]").click
    find_field("cars_to_edit[#{Car.second.id}]").click
    find_field("cars_to_edit[#{Car.third.id}]").click
    click_button('Delete cars')

    cars_to_be_deleted = Car.where(id: Car.first(3).map(&:id)).ids
    click_button('Yes')

    expect(page).to have_text(
                      'Some selected cars have been successfully deleted from the portal, however, some have not. The '\
                      "following cars have not been deleted from the portal:\n\n#{@first_three_cars_car_numbers[0]}".upcase
                    )
    expect(Car.count).to eq(98)
    expect(Car.where(id: cars_to_be_deleted).length).to eq(1)
  end
end
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! It's becoming quite frustrating lol.

Comment: What would prevent the destruction of some `Car` records? A DB constraint? A callback?

Comment: I was thinking maybe a dropped connection to the server/DB. It would be an edge case most likely. In your opinion, is it even worth accounting for something like this? Should I just assume `destroy_all` will do its job every time?

Comment: I do think it's a bit too defensive, I'll put some thought into an answer though

Comment: Okay, thanks so much! Also, I did write a unit test for the code that handles the flash messages, but I wanted to write an E2E test for it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to "mock" not deleting a record for a test could be to use the `block` version of `.to receive` to return a `falsy` value.

The argument for the block is the instance of the record that would be `:destroy`ed.

Since we have this instance, we can check for an arbitrary record to be "not destroyed" and have the block return `nil`, which would indicate a "failure" from the `:destroy` method.

In this example, we check for the record of the first `Car` record in the database and return `nil` if it is.
If it is not the first record, we use the `:delete` method, as to not cause an infinite loop in the test (the test would keep calling the mock `:destroy`).

```
allow_any_instance_of(Car).to receive(:destroy) { |car|
      # use car.delete to prevent infinite loop with the mocked :destroy method
      if car.id != Car.first.id
        car.delete
      end
      # this will return `nil`, which means failure from the :destroy method
}
```

You could create a method that accepts a list of records and decide which one you want to `:destroy` for more accurate testing!

I am sure there are other ways to work around this, but this is the best we have found so far :)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a specific reason why the deletion might fail you can simulate that case.

Say you have a `RaceResult` record that must always refer to a valid `Car` and you have a DB constraint enforcing this (in Postgres: `ON DELETE RESTRICT`). You could write a test that creates the `RaceResult` records for some of your `Car` records:

```
it 'Cars prevented from deletion are reported` do
  ...
  do_not_delete_cars = Car.where(id: Car.first(3).map(&:id)).ids
  do_not_delete_cars.each { |car| RaceResult.create(car: car, ...) }

  click_button('Yes')

  expect(page).to have_text(...
end
```

Another option would be to use some knowledge of how your controller interacts with the model:

```
  allow(Car).to receive(:destroy_list_of_cars).with(1,2,3).and_return(false) # or whatever your method would return
```

This would not actually run the `destroy_list_of_cars` method, so all the records would still be there in the DB. Then you can expect error messages for each of your selected records.

Or since `destroy_all` calls each record's `destroy` method, you could mock that method:

```
allow_any_instance_of('Car').to receive(:destroy).and_return(false) # simulates a callback halting things
```

`allow_any_instance_of` makes tests brittle however.

Finally, you could consider just not anticipating problems before they exist (maybe you don't even need the bulk delete page to be this helpful?). If your users see a more generic error, is there a page they could filter to verify for themselves what might still be there? (there's a lot of factors to consider here, it depends on the importance of the feature to the business and what sort of things could go wrong if the data is inconsistent).

Comment: So I've tried to do something like this:
`before do car = Car.first allow(car).to receive(:destroy).and_return(false) end`
But it doesn't prevent the record from being destroyed.

Comment: Yep that doesn’t work because although it’s the same record in the DB, it’s not the same object insurance in memory. That’s why you’d need to use allow_any_instance_of(Car)

Comment: Is there a way I can call `allow_any_instance_of(Car)`, but then narrow it down to a single record? I think I tried something like `allow_any_instance_of(Car).to receive(:destroy).with(Car.first.id).and_return(false)`, but it didn't work as intended.

Comment: I don’t think so. You would have to know how your code is finding the instances and mock that: allow(Car).to receive(:where).and_return([mockcar1, mockcar2]) then allow (mockcar1).to receive(:destroy) etc… that’s a test that knows a lot about the implementation of the code under test though.